# QNetworkReply error "Connection closed" when getting a simple URL

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I'm trying to make a simple file downloader. Here is my code segment for downloading a URL; This code works fine, if I try to get simple URLs like "http://stackoverflow.com".
But when I specify URLs which **redirects**, it throws an error saying **"Connection closed".**

```
//Sets a sample URL which redirects.
QString url = "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gretl/gretl/1.9.92/gretl-1.9.92.tar.xz"

QNetworkAccessManager * networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

QNetworkRequest * networkRequest = new QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url));

//Getting the URL
QNetworkReply * networkReply = networkAccessManager->get(*networkRequest);
```

Additionally I've connected the following signal-slot to recognize network errors:

```
 //Connects networkReply object's error signal to a slot which prints the error.
 connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(printError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

Here is the slot which prints errors if networkReply's error signal is emitted:

```
void printError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code)
{
     qDebug() << "Network Error Code: " << code;
     qDebug() << networkReply->errorString();
}
```

---

Because of this error, **networkReply** object never receives any header.

My need is to read the HTTP status code by this method: `QNetworkReply::attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute)`

I can't read the HTTP Status code, because I don't get the headers.

Can anyone say whats going on?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Handling_an_HTTP_redirect_with_QNetworkAccessManager) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809310/qnetworkreply-and-301-redirect) are good examples of handling this scenario - basically you add a slot for [finished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal, then check the HTTP status code for 301 and/or `QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute` attribute to see if you are being redirected and if so issue a new request for the redirect link.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't set a user agent as in the examples. It works when specify the user agent. I think the server drops the connection when it finds out I don't have a user agent.