# download a file by a direct link using QNetworkAcessManager

Tags: c++, qt, curl, qnetworkaccessmanager, qt5.8

I'm using QNetworkAcessManager to download a pdf file from a direct link this the link here
but it download nothing and the QByteArray size is 0 I try it on another link of mp3 files and many others and it works fine but I want to know why this link can't be downloaded I try using Curl to download it and the same problem
so I try to do it in java but it give me an error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: www.proz.com/ht/profile_resources/022198_r4551c465d7a53.doc
```

when I search on this error the solve of it was to encode it so I back again and do it in Qt and encode the URL using this

```
//using QUrl To endcode the link
reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(QUrl(Link).toEncoded())));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(CollectFile()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(DocDownloaded()));
```

but the same problem for both java and Qt after encoded so what casue this problem and why it's not download any solution using QNetworkacessManager or using Curl 
**Update**
the url of the file i want to download

```
http://www.proz.com/ht/profile_resources/009424_r57075c01ae812.pdf
```

Thank in advance

Comment: From the java error it looks as if your URL is missing a scheme.  Can you edit your question to include the URL (or even just the result of [`QUrl::scheme`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#scheme))?

Comment: Checking things out with `wget` suggests the URL is actually a redirect.  Try setting the [`QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum) attribute in the [`QNetworkRequest`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setAttribute) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to construct QNetworkRequest as:

```
 QNetworkRequest(QUrl(Link))
```

without 'toEncoded'?

According to example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#QUrl-2), you need to use [QUrl::fromEncoded](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromEncoded) to conscruct QUrl from encoded url, or simply skip all the manipulations.

Comment: Yes I try without encoded the same result it didn't download anything

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem but because I have a little experience in web development I don't know why this happend
I solve it by when I download the file from normal web browser firefox or any or using Internet download manager application the Link is change 
from :

```
http://www.proz.com/ht/profile_resources/009424_r57075c01ae812.pdf
```

to :

```
http://cdn3.proz.com/profile_resources/009424_r57075c01ae812.pdf
```

so when I copy the second link it can be downloaded now from my application or using Curl but don't know an explanation to that so if anyone can help and explain this why is this happened and the link change when I put it in internet download manager and give me the new link I will appreciate 
this how i solve the problem but with no explain why this happened

Comment: Right! Now it's clear: you didn't actually have a direct link. The first one redirects to another one. It's a known issue - redirection support just added lately. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36386724/3697939