# Follow redirects in QT5.5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I have a program that works well from Qt 5.6

```
const QUrl qurl(url);
QNetworkRequest request(qurl);
//github redirects the request, so this attribute must be set to true, otherwise returns nothing
//from qt5.6
request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkReply * reply = manager.get(request);
```

Unfortunately this only works from Qt 5.6

Could anyone help me to make the redirect o Qt5.5 (Ubuntu 16.04) I guess I have to follow the redirection manually, but I have found no tutorial on it.

I found a solution for Qt4 -> [QNetworkReply and 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809310/qnetworkreply-and-301-redirect)

I was hoping there is something more "updated" for Qt5.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QNetworkReply and 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809310/qnetworkreply-and-301-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the way I have solved it following Qt4 style as in [QNetworkReply and 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809310/qnetworkreply-and-301-redirect).

If anyone has a better solution please post

```
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QVariant possibleRedirectUrl;
    QNetworkReply * reply;

    QUrl qurl;
    qurl.setUrl(url);

    //we check if there is any redirect to follow it
    //from Qt 5.6 redirects can be automatically followed by setting
    //request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
    //here is done automatically becaus of Ubuntu 16.04 Qt version (5.5)

    do{
        qInfo() <<"Downloading " << qurl;

        QNetworkRequest request(qurl);
        reply = manager.get(request);

        qInfo() << "waiting to finish...";

        _timeout=false;
        _timer->start(timeout);

        //if download takes more time that set on timeout cancel download
        while(!_timeout){
            qApp->processEvents();
            if(reply->isFinished()) break;
        }

        _timeout = false;

        qInfo() << "finished!";

        possibleRedirectUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
        qurl = possibleRedirectUrl.toUrl();
        qInfo() << qurl;

    }while(possibleRedirectUrl.isValid());
```